# Dipole moment in primary polarization mechanism in a dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, solid-state-physics, dielectric, dipole-moment

The question I have is regarding material from an old University book I am currently reading, Chapter 13, "The Solid State", Third Edition, H.M Rosenburg.

And it states that the first mechanism of polarization is when an electric field $E$ acts on an *individual atom* and as a result that atom acquires a dipole moment $p$, and this is defined in one of the two following ways:

$$p=\alpha E \tag{1}$$
$$p=\alpha \epsilon E \tag{2}$$

where $\alpha$ is the polarizability of the atom.

So my question is really two questions,

A) How would one go about deriving a value for $\alpha$ for a given element/isotope?

B) What criterion should govern one's selection of the definition of $p$ between (1) & (2)? As the reader can see, one is a factor of the other, I have not done any physics in a long time but this really seems  strange or counterintuitive.

Additional note relevant:

This [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59422/polarizability-and-the-clausius-mossotti-relation?rq=1) is essentially making the same point as A) so the difference in definitions as far as I can figure at this point is in regards to whether the electric field $E$ is the independently produced external electric field, or the effective electric field acting on the atom, which I guess would be the net field in adding the external field and the one consequently generated by the electron cloud under it's application, but I'm not 100 percent on this.

If this is indeed the case, then the epsilon in definition (2) must surely be *relative* permittivity, assuming polarizability in both definitions is measured in the same physical units.

Because this type of polarization occurs in all dielectric materials, I am in preference of definition (2) as the epsilon as well as the effective electric field calculation quantifies what we can attribute to be a measure of the extent the dielectric medium contributes to the dipole moment induced in the atom,which *I hope* will make it easier to quantify what extent the nature of the atom itself contributes to the dipole moments magnitude.